# ggplotly works in RStudio console but not rendering in shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am working on created a shiny app and I wrote a function to display a plotly. The function works fine and prints the plot when I run it in the console, but the ggplotly histogram will not render when I run the app. I do not receive any errors when running the function in the console nor when I try to run the app. The graphs just do not show up in the app. Here is the function, which I wrote in a helper file:

```
# making function to display simulated state-level pv2ps

pv2p_plot <- function(x) {

  # filter based on input$state from ui.R
  # getting text to specify the predicted pv2p and the chance of victory
  
  pv2p <- sims %>% 
    drop_na() %>% 
    filter(state == x) %>% 
    mutate(d_pv2p = sim_dvotes_2020 / (sim_rvotes_2020 + sim_dvotes_2020),
           r_pv2p = 1 - d_pv2p) %>% 
    summarise(d_pv2p = mean(d_pv2p) * 100,
              r_pv2p = mean(r_pv2p) * 100)
  
  win_prob <- sims %>% 
    mutate(biden_win = ifelse(sim_dvotes_2020 > sim_rvotes_2020, 1, 0)) %>% 
    group_by(state) %>% 
    summarise(pct_biden_win = mean(biden_win, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    filter(pct_biden_win < 1 & pct_biden_win > 0) %>% 
    mutate(pct_trump_win = 1 - pct_biden_win) %>% 
    select(state, pct_biden_win, pct_trump_win) %>% 
    filter(state == x)
  
  pv2p_lab <- paste0("Forecasted Two-Party Popular Vote: ", round(pv2p$d_pv2p, 2), "% for Biden and ", round(pv2p$r_pv2p, 2), "% for Trump") 
  win_lab <- paste0("Forecasted Probability of Electoral College Victory: ", round(win_prob$pct_biden_win * 100, 2), "% for Biden and ", round(win_prob$pct_trump_win * 100, 2), "% for Trump")
  
  pv_plot <- sims %>% 
    filter(state == x) %>% 
    mutate(Democrat = sim_dvotes_2020 / (sim_dvotes_2020 + sim_rvotes_2020),
           Republican = 1 - Democrat) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(Democrat, Republican), names_to = "party") %>% 
    ggplot(aes(value, fill = party)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count)),
                       text = paste0("Probability: ", round(after_stat(count / sum(count)), 5))), bins = 1000, alpha = 0.5, position = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Democrat", "Republican"),
                      labels = c("Biden", "Trump"),
                      values = c(muted("blue"), "red3")) +
    labs(title = paste("Simulated Two-Party Popular Vote \nin", x),
         x = "Predicted Share of the Two-Party Popular Vote",
         y = "Probability",
         fill = "Candidate",
         subtitle = pv2p_lab) +
    theme_hodp()
  
  print(ggplotly(pv_plot, tooltip = "text"))
}
```

And this is my UI & server code from the app:

```
 # loaded libraries, read in data, and created functions in other file to keep
# this script nice and clean

source("helper.R")

ui <- navbarPage(
    
    # Application title
    "Presidential Forecast in Retrospect",
    
    tabPanel(
        "About",
        includeHTML(file.path("pages/about.html"))
    ),
    
    navbarMenu("Forecast Simulations",
               tabPanel("State-by-State Two-Party Popular Vote",
                   
                    fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                        tabsetPanel(
                               tabPanel("Estimated Vote Share", 
                                    selectInput("state",
                                                "State:",
                                                sims %>% pull(state) %>% unique() %>% sort()),
                                    plotlyOutput("statesimPlotly")),
                               tabPanel("Probability of Victory",
                                   selectInput("state_type",
                                               "State Category:",
                                               types %>% pull(type) %>% unique()),
                                    plotlyOutput("statevictoryPlotly")
                                   )
                               )
                            )
                    ),
         
               tabPanel("Predicted Vote Margin Map",
                        # creating this page to show the win margin
                        includeHTML(file.path("pages/margin_maps.html"))

                )
    )
)


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$statesimPlotly <- renderPlotly({

        # calling function that I defined at the top of the app
        pv2p_plot(input$state)
        
    })
    
    output$statevictoryPlotly <- renderPlotly(
        
        # calling function from helper to make this plot
        state_win_probs(input$state_type)
    )
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As I said above, the function works fine in my console. Most people who have had issues with this online are not using the proper output/render functions (e.g. using renderPlot instead of renderPlotly), but I am not seeing what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your selectInput. You pass `plotlyOutput("statesimPlotly")` as an argument to selectInput

Comment: @stefan I completely missed that--great catch & thanks! Unfortunately, I fixed that and am still having the same issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, in the `state_type` input you use `select` instead of `pull`, so you have a data.frame as the choices

Comment: @starja Also good catch - thanks! Unfortunately that did not solve the problem either (neither of the plotly outputs are rendering in my shiny app)

Comment: This *shouldn’t* cause the issue but you can/should remove the `print` statement from your function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That also didn't change things. I added the `print` because some people solved the same problem by adding a print (so Shiny was creating the plot but now displaying it without wrapping the plot with `print`).

Comment: For now I found a workaround by replacing my making a Shiny .Rmd file. The functions all work in their and the plotlys render. However, it would be helpful to know what I am doing wrong in the case that I want to make my app more sophisticated than an .Rmd can handle.